# About Fast Conv Layer implication in cs231n assignment

Tags: deep-learning

In the famous Cs231n assignment 2 , in the implication of fast Convolution Layer They use Stride Tricks to get the im2col operation.The code is as follows.

```
def conv_forward_strides(x, w, b, conv_param):
    N, C, H, W = x.shape
    F, _, HH, WW = w.shape
    stride, pad = conv_param['stride'], conv_param['pad']

    # Check dimensions
    #assert (W + 2 * pad - WW) % stride == 0, 'width does not work'
    #assert (H + 2 * pad - HH) % stride == 0, 'height does not work'

    # Pad the input
    p = pad
    x_padded = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (p, p), (p, p)), mode='constant')

    # Figure out output dimensions
    H += 2 * pad
    W += 2 * pad
    out_h = (H - HH) // stride + 1
    out_w = (W - WW) // stride + 1

    # Perform an im2col operation by picking clever strides
    shape = (C, HH, WW, N, out_h, out_w)
    strides = (H * W, W, 1, C * H * W, stride * W, stride)
    strides = x.itemsize * np.array(strides)
    x_stride = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x_padded,
                  shape=shape, strides=strides)
    x_cols = np.ascontiguousarray(x_stride)
    x_cols.shape = (C * HH * WW, N * out_h * out_w)

    # Now all our convolutions are a big matrix multiply
    res = w.reshape(F, -1).dot(x_cols) + b.reshape(-1, 1)

    # Reshape the output
    res.shape = (F, N, out_h, out_w)
    out = res.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)

    # Be nice and return a contiguous array
    # The old version of conv_forward_fast doesn't do this, so for a fair
    # comparison we won't either
    out = np.ascontiguousarray(out)

    cache = (x, w, b, conv_param, x_cols)
    return out, cache
```

Now how is the Shape and strides arguement of as_strided() calculated ? I am having a hard time visualizing it .
Also does this implementation suffer from extra memory problem ? It seems like it doesnt like other im2col implementations as No new memory isnt created i guess.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to consider here: The data format is NCHW.

So if you have all your input data in a consistent block of memory and move by 1, you would move in W (=column), since W has the lowest priority.

Now what offset do you need to move one row? H (=row) is the next priority level. One row consists of W columns. So if you want to jump to the next row, you need an offset of W.

Now you want to move in C (=channel). To go to the next channel, you have to skip all the rows (=H) of the last channel, each row has W columns. So one channel has H * W elements.

Now if you want to move by one mini-batch (=N), you will have to move by all the channels (=C). One channel contains H * W elements, so one mini-batch contains C  *  H * W elements for all channels.

And there you go with all your strides!